# Classical first-order model theory via hyperdoctrines

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, boolean-algebras

I have been reading [this discussion](https://diagonalargument.com/mathnotes/first-order-categorical-logic-the-series/) by John Baez and Michael Weiss and I find this approach to model theory using boolean hyper-doctrines very interesting. One of their goal was to arrive at a proof of Godel's completeness theorem in this language, which I was very hyped for, but unfortunately, it seems like they never really finished that series of blog posts.

I was therefore wondering if there is any other place where I can read further on classical first-order model theory done in the categorical language of hyperdoctrines. I am not a logician at all, so I'm looking for something fairly introductory that doesn't already assume a good knowledge of model theory.

Comment: The nLab article on Goedel incompleteness takes a hyperdoctrinal approach.

Comment: @ToddTrimble That's the incompleteness theorem. This question is about the completeness theorem, which nLab doesn't seem to have a very complete article on.

Comment: @JamesHanson Golly, I'm aware of that, and it's why I didn't post my comment as an answer, but just as a possible point of interest.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Ah, sorry, it's just a fairly common confusion.

Comment: Lawvere's notion of hyperdoctrine is *very* heavy machinery, incorporating *dependent* types but also restricting to a logic similar to that of $\mathbf{Set}$ (or a topos).  The most important point is that the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ are the right and left **adjoints to** (Lawvere said substitution, but more accurately) **weakening**. Weakening means pretending that a formula involves more variables than actually appear in it.  By the way, classical logic doesn't simplify anything.